# Extend Table border to the page footer

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print a table in full page of Detail Band, if the table having only four rows then also i want to print the table on full page.

For more clarity i added image, please refer and give me some suggestion to achieve the same.

In the below image i have some empty space. but i need to extend the table border till page footer. i tried with some empty rows, but i have no luck. can anyone help me?

[image]

Expected Result Like:

[image]

Comment: are you using jr:table  or not, can you include your jrxml?

Comment: Yes I am using jr:table,  my condition is that the table if the query returns only two rows then also the table border need to print on whole detail band.

Comment: For now my only solution would be to use the background band, hence put the border in background... and terms and conditions in pageFooter, there is probably a better solution thats why this is just a comment...